# How can I modify this SQL SELECT statement to change non-numeric values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

The dataset I am using can be found [here](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Education/School-Demographics-and-Accountability-Snapshot-20/ihfw-zy9j).

I am using SSIS to upload the dataset into MS SQL Server.

I uploaded everything as text, and am trying to create a working table with proper data types by inserting values from the raw table.

```
CREATE TABLE [WRK_demographics]
(
        [RowNumber]         INT IDENTITY(1,1)
        ,[DBN]              VARCHAR(10)
        ,[Name]             VARCHAR(1000)
        ,[schoolyear]       VARCHAR(100)
        ,[fl_percent]       FLOAT
        ,[frl_percent]      FLOAT
        ,[total_enrollment] INT
        ,[grade9]           INT
        ,[grade10]          INT
        ,[grade11]          INT
        ,[grade12]          INT
        ,[ell_num]          INT
        ,[ell_percent]      FLOAT
        ,[sped_num]         INT
        ,[sped_percent]     FLOAT
        ,[ctt_num]          INT
        ,[selfcontained_num] INT
        ,[asian_num]        INT
        ,[asian_per]        FLOAT
        ,[black_num]        INT
        ,[black_per]        FLOAT
        ,[hispanic_num]     INT
        ,[hispanic_per]     FLOAT
        ,[white_num]        INT
        ,[white_per]        FLOAT
        ,[male_num]         INT
        ,[male_per]         FLOAT
        ,[female_num]       INT
        ,[female_per]       FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO [WRK_demographics]
(       
        [DBN]
        ,[Name]
        ,[schoolyear]
        ,[fl_percent]
        ,[frl_percent]
        ,[total_enrollment]
        ,[grade9]
        ,[grade10]
        ,[grade11]
        ,[grade12]
        ,[ell_num]
        ,[ell_percent]
        ,[sped_num]
        ,[sped_percent]
        ,[ctt_num]
        ,[selfcontained_num]
        ,[asian_num]
        ,[asian_per]
        ,[black_num]
        ,[black_per]
        ,[hispanic_num]
        ,[hispanic_per]
        ,[white_num]
        ,[white_per]
        ,[male_num]
        ,[male_per]
        ,[female_num]
        ,[female_per]               
)
SELECT 
        [DBN]
        ,[Name]
        ,[schoolyear]
        ,[fl_percent]
        ,[frl_percent]
        ,[total_enrollment]
        ,[grade9]
        ,[grade10]
        ,[grade11]
        ,[grade12]
        ,[ell_num]
        ,[ell_percent]
        ,[sped_num]
        ,[sped_percent]
        ,[ctt_num]
        ,[selfcontained_num]
        ,[asian_num]
        ,[asian_per]
        ,[black_num]
        ,[black_per]
        ,[hispanic_num]
        ,[hispanic_per]
        ,[white_num]
        ,[white_per]
        ,[male_num]
        ,[male_per]
        ,[female_num]
        ,[female_per]
FROM [RAW_demographics_20170706]
```

However, the issue I am having is that for cells where there is no value, there is text instead of a null cell. So, implicit conversion cannot convert the data to `int/float`. Is there a way I can modify the `SELECT` statement to update the values of non-numeric cells to `NULL`? If I didn't have so many columns I would update each one in the raw table like this before inserting into the working table:

```
UPDATE [RAW_demographics_20170706]
SET [fl_percent] = NULL
WHERE ISNUMERIC([fl_percent]) <> 1
```

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient path to take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to use a case statement since your error should be coming from empty strings not an actual `NULL`

```
SELECT 
        [DBN]
        ,[Name]
        ,[schoolyear]
        ,case when [fl_percent] = '' then 0.0 else fl_percent end
        ,case when [frl_percent] = '' then 0.0 else flr_percent end
        ...
        ...
        ,case when [grade12] = '' then 0 else grade12 end
        ...
FROM [RAW_demographics_20170706]
```

I also wouldn't use `ISNUMERIC` for this situation. It will cause problems as it returns true for an array of cases other than an int or float.

These return true, but would fail for conversions:

```
select isnumeric('$') 
select isnumeric('1e4')
etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what [TRY_CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql) is for: "Returns a value cast to the specified data type if the cast succeeds; otherwise, returns null."

Comment: So would I need a TRY_CAST statement for each column?